# How can I trigger a Button Rollover from a function call in Animate CC?

Tags: createjs, animate-cc

When you create a Button Symbol in Animate, it has the Up, Over, Down states.
Is there a way to trigger that button Over state from a function?

something like:

```
button.onRollOver();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Stage` handles mouse interaction, and determines what is interacted with. Once it has figured that out, it dispatches an event from that object ([source](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/src/easeljs/display/Stage.js#L872)):

```
var evt = new createjs.MouseEvent(type, bubbles, false, o.x, o.y, nativeEvent, pointerId, pointerId === this._primaryPointerID || pointerId === -1, o.rawX, o.rawY, relatedTarget);
target.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

You should be able to replicate this fairly simply:

```
var evt = new createjs.MouseEvent("rollover", false, x, y, null, 0, true, x, y, null);
myBtn.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

I am not sure exactly what this accomplishes though, since you could just fire the listener(s) that would otherwise get called yourself.

Note also that there is a difference between "mouseover" and "rollover" events.
Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking at it the wrong way. DispatchEvent makes total sense. Thanks for the help!